# Source File not compiled with latest version of DEV C++ and OpenCV 3.X version

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, dev-c++

I installed latest version of DEV C++ and OpenCV 3.4.1.
As per instructions on various websites the lib folder is present in opencv folder but in versions higher than 2.3 lib folders are present in inlude\opencv\vcxx\lib
and inlude\opencv\vcxx\bin

While setting up DEV C++ with opencv I give following in Bin 
C:\OpenCV..\inlude\opencv\vcxx\bin

for Lib:
C:\OpenCV..\inlude\opencv\vcxx\lib

But when i run simple Hello world program also it says source file not compiled.
I noticed lot of issues when setting up OpenCV versions greater than 2.3 with DEV C++ due to absence of LIB folder in C:\OpenCV\

Please suggest what to do

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? Also, you say `.. in versions higher than 2.3 lib folders are present ..` and then say `.. versions greater than 2.3 with DEV C++ due to absence of LIB folder ..` so which is it?

Comment: @TreytenCarey The exact issue is when i even try to run Hello world with compiler as OpenCV it says source file not compiled.

Comment: @TreytenCarey Though with OpenCV 2.2.0 everything works fine but if I install OpenCV 3.X versions even Hello world does not work properly

Answer (score -1):

The folder is called "include", not "inlude".

Comment: Small typo error..but any suggestions on the solution?